# Как остановить цикл автокликера?

Tags: python, циклы

Написал автокликер кнопкой пробела. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при удержании пробела - скрипт работал, при отпускании - переставал. Но у меня работает так: нажал на пробел - работа пошла. Чтобы остановить, нужно закрыть сам скрипт.

```py
import keyboard
from time import sleep

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
       while True:
               sleep (0.01)
               keyboard.send('space')
```

Comment: Во-первых вместо `while True` наверное `while keyboard.is_pressed('space')`, а то у вас никогда цикл просто не закончится. А во-вторых может на другую клавишу повесить инициацию действия, а то не получится, что скрипт сам себе `space` нажимает и его же опять ловит?

Answer (score 1):

Вы проверяете нажатие кнопки, а не то, что она зажата в данный момент времени.

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard

while True:
    event = keyboard.read_event()
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN and event.name == 'space':
        keyboard.send('space')
    sleep(.01)
```